# Can anyone explain one sentence in the proof of the claim that monotone functions are continuous except at a countable number of points?

Tags: measure-theory

Claim (page 108 of Royden's Real Analysis): Let f be monotone on the open interval (a,b). Then f is continuous except at a countable number of points.

In the proof, the book states that

> assume (a,b) is bounded and f is increasing on [a, b]. Otherwise,
>   express (a, b) as the union of an ascending sequence of open, bounded
>   intervals, the closures of which are contained in (a, b), and take the
>   union of the discontinuities in each of this countable collection of
>   intervals.

What does the following part mean?

> Otherwise, express (a, b) as the union of an ascending sequence of open, bounded intervals, the closures of which are contained in (a, b), and take the union of the discontinuities in each of this countable collection of intervals.

Why is the book assuming f is increasing on [a, b] instead of (a, b)? 
Does the claim still hold if f is monotone on closed intervals?

Answer (score 2):

The phrase means(I think): if $(a, b)$ is not bounded, for example when $a=-\infty$,  write 
$$(a, b)=\bigcup_{i=1} ^{\infty}(a_i, b_i),$$
where the $(a_i, b_i)$ are bounded intervals, $a_i \neq a$ and $b_i \neq b$ for all $i$, and $(a_i, b_i) \subset (a_{i+1}, b_{i+1})$ for all i. Now if you prove the case $(a, b)$ is bounded, you have proven the case where $(a, b)$ is unbounded, since a countable union of countable sets is countable. If $f$ is not increasing on $[a, b]$, then $f$ is increasing on every $[a_i, b_i]$. So by the same reasoning we can assume $(a, b)$ is bounded and $f$ is increasing on $[a, b]$. And yes, the claim also holds if $f$ is monotone on a closed interval, it follows from the theorem, because if $f$ is monotone on $[a, b]$ it is monotone on $(a, b)$, so $f$ has countably many discontinuities in $(a, b)$. Other discontinuities of $f$ in $[a, b]$ could only be either $a$ or $b$. But adding two elements to a countable set does not change it from being countable.